Change Domain Name
I have my wordpress site hosted live. The site works with example.shop but it doesn't work with www.example.shop. I tried changing it in the wordpress backend(wp-admin) and even in the cpanel, doesn't seem to help. Can anybody help me out with this.
I tried changing it in the wordpress backend(wp-admin) and even in the cpanel, doesn't seem to help. Can anybody help me out with this.
Note:I want both the domains to be active.

WordPress should cope OK with this automatically: whichever one is in your site settings will be the main version, and the other will redirect to it. Or if you want both to work without the redirect then you can set that up too with a little code.

Can you explain exactly how it doesn't work? Is the problem DNS resolution, firewall, connects to the server OK but the domain isn't recognised, a redirect loop, something else?
